# R - Combining duplicate rows within dataframe in R :

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe as below: please note that `COL1` is having duplicate entries

```
COL1 COL2 COL3
10   hai   2   
10   hai   3
10   pal   1
```

I want the output to be like this as shown below: i.e `COL1` should have the unique entry alone(10), `COL2` should contain the merged entries under it without duplicates(hai pal), and `COL3` should contain the sum of entries(2+3+1=6)

OUTPUT:

```
COL1   COL2     COL3
10    hai pal    6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps we need to aggregate by group.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1`), grouped by 'COL1', `paste` the `unique` elements in 'COL2' together as well as get the `sum` of 'COL3'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,.(COL2  = paste(unique(COL2), collapse=" "), COL3= sum(COL3)) , by = COL1]
#     COL1    COL2 COL3
#1:    10 hai pal    6
```

Comment: and with `dplyr`,  `df %>% group_by(COL1) %>%  summarise(COL2 = paste0(unique(COL2), collapse = " "), COL3 = sum(COL3))`

Comment: Thanks Ronak....Just a small correction... I want to store the  output of ur statement into another dataframe. How shud I do this????

Comment: Anybody else who can help with this? Ronak's piece of code works fine, but I'm unable to store the output to a dataframe.

Comment: @Rambo  You just need to assign it i.e. `df2 <- setDT(df1)[,.(COL2  = paste(unique(COL2), collapse=" "), COL3= sum(COL3)) , by = COL1]`  If you need to convert to data.frame, then `setDT(df2)`

Comment: @akrun I get this error when I use setDT (Error: could not find function "setDT")...... I'm a novice to R so pls guide me

Comment: @Rambo You need to load `library(data.table)`.  If it is not installed then `install.packages("data.table")`

Comment: @akrun Great!... This works for me..Glad you helped :) :)