# R - Combining dataframe rows on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

**EDIT**
I have a dataframe as below: please note that `COL1` is having duplicate entries, COL2 & COL3 can be in any order i.e they can occur anywhere between other columns in the dataframe...and there is no limitation on the exact number of columns in data frame.. there may be additional columns too appended later.....

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL5 COL6 COL7 ... ... (goes on)
 10  hai    2   15  10    6   ... ...
 10  hai    3   25  20   12   ... ...
 10  pal    1   35  30   18   ... ...
 11  rfm    9   22  32    9   ... ...
  9  rtf    8   34  54   10   ... ...
```

I also have a vector as below:

```
number <- c("first", "last")
```

I want the output to be like this as shown below: i.e

- `COL1` should have the unique entry alone(10,11,9)
- `COL2` should contain the merged entries under it without duplicates(hai pal), *unique rows with distinct COL1 values shouldn't be considered for merge. Only duplicate rows of COL1 values should be merged...and COL2 can occur anywhere in the data frame(it will not always be the 2nd column)*
- `COL3` should contain the sum of entries(2+3+1=6). *Sum should be calculated for duplicate rows alone. Duplicate rows are identified based on COL1 values...and COL3 can also occur anywhere in the dataframe(it will not always be the 3rd column).*

And for `COL5`, `COL6`, `COL7`(i may have many columns appended later...not necessary that I have only 3 columns for this condition) i need a generalized piece of code such that if the input is given as "first" from the vector named "number", the values of first observation from duplicate rows of all remaining columns need to be taken i.e, the first row values. And if the input is given as "last" from the vector named "number", the values of last observation from duplicate rows from all remaining columns need to be taken i.e, the last row values.

**Note:** The output should be stored in another dataframe

**OUTPUT(if input is given as "first"):**

```
COL1    COL2   COL3 COL5 COL6 COL7
10      hai pal 6   15    10    6
11      rfm     9   22    32    9
 9      rtf     8   34    54   10
```

In the above output: COL5, COL6, COL7 contain the first row values of duplicate entries

**OUTPUT(if input is given as "last"):**

```
COL1    COL2   COL3 COL5 COL6 COL7
10      hai pal 6   15    10    6
11      rfm     9   22    32    9
 9      rtf     8   34    54   10
```

In the above output: COL5, COL6, COL7 contain the last row values of duplicate entries

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr`.

This is basically just an extension of my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000667/r-combining-duplicate-rows-within-dataframe-in-r#comment67282644_40001493) on your previous question.

```
library(dplyr)
new_df <- df %>% group_by(COL1) %>% 
                 summarise(COL2 = paste0(unique(COL2), collapse = " "), 
                           COL3 = sum(COL3), 
                           COL5 = first(COL5), 
                           COL6 = first(COL6), 
                           COL7 = first(COL7))
new_df
#    COL1    COL2     COL3  COL5  COL6  COL7
#    <int>   <chr>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1    10    hai pal     6    15    10     6
```

**EDIT**

You can do the similar operation using `last` instead of `first` in `dplyr`

If there are only two options (first, last), you can check the condition with an `if` statement

```
if(number == "first") {
     new_df <- df %>% group_by(COL1) %>% 
                      summarise(COL2 = paste0(unique(COL2), collapse = " "), 
                                COL3 = sum(COL3), 
                                COL5 = first(COL5), 
                                COL6 = first(COL6), 
                                COL7 = first(COL7))
} else 
{ 
     new_df <- df %>% group_by(COL1) %>% 
                      summarise(COL2 = paste0(unique(COL2), collapse = " "), 
                                COL3 = sum(COL3), 
                                COL5 = last(COL5), 
                                COL6 = last(COL6), 
                                COL7 = last(COL7))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(COL2 = paste(unique(COL2), collapse= " "),
               COL3 = sum(COL3),
               COL5 = COL5[1L],
               COL6 = COL6[1L],
               COL7 = COL7[1L]), by = COL1]
#   COL1    COL2 COL3 COL5 COL6 COL7
#1:   10 hai pal    6   15   10    6
```

---

If we are using the devel version of `data.table` i.e. v.1.9.7, then this can be simplified as

```
setDT(df1)[, c(COL2 = paste(unique(COL2), collapse=" "), 
             COL3 = sum(COL3) ,.SD[1L]), by = COL1, .SDcols=COL5:COL7]
#    COL1    COL2 COL3 COL5 COL6 COL7
#1:   10 hai pal    6   15   10    6
```

If we need the last rows, use `.SD[.N]` instead of `.SD[1L]` i.e.

```
setDT(df1)[, c(COL2 = paste(unique(COL2), collapse=" "),  
     COL3 = sum(COL3) ,.SD[.N]), by = COL1, .SDcols=COL5:COL7]
#   COL1    COL2 COL3 COL5 COL6 COL7
#1:   10 hai pal    6   35   30   18
```

Instructions to install the devel version of data.table are [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Comment: I'm unable to install v1.9.7 since it is not supported in Rv3.2.1 .... Getting the below error

Comment: package ‘data.table’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)

Comment: @Rambo That is strange.  The new R version is R 3.3.1.  It is better to update to new R version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with base R:

```
get.df <- function(df, input) {
  cbind.data.frame(COL1=unique(df$COL1), 
                   COL2=paste(unique(df$COL2), collapse=' '),
                   COL3=sum(df$COL3),
                   df[ifelse(input == 'first', 1, nrow(df)),names(df)[-1:-3]])
}

get.df(df, 'first')
# COL1    COL2 COL3 COL5 COL6 COL7
# 1   10 hai pal    6   15   10    6

get.df(df, 'last')
# COL1    COL2 COL3 COL5 COL6 COL7
# 3   10 hai pal    6   35   30   18
```

As per your new requirement, try this:

```
df <- read.table(text='COL1 COL2 COL3 COL5 COL6 COL7
                 10  hai    2   15  10    6
                 10  hai    3   25  20   12
                 10  pal    1   35  30   18
                 11  rfm    9   22  32    9
                  9  rtf    8   34  54   10', header=TRUE)

get.df <- function(df, input) {

  dups <- unique(df[duplicated(df$COL1),]$COL1)
  df.dup <- df[df$COL1 %in% dups,]
  df.nondup <- df[!(df$COL1 %in% dups),]
  rbind(cbind.data.frame(COL1=unique(df.dup$COL1), 
                   COL2=paste(unique(df.dup$COL2), collapse=' '),
                   COL3=sum(df.dup$COL3),
                   df.dup[ifelse(input == 'first', 1, nrow(df.dup)),names(df.dup)[-1:-3]]),
        df.nondup)
}

number <- c("first", "last")

get.df(df, 'first')

COL1    COL2 COL3 COL5 COL6 COL7
1   10 hai pal    6   15   10    6
4   11     rfm    9   22   32    9
5    9     rtf    8   34   54   10

get.df(df, 'last')

COL1    COL2 COL3 COL5 COL6 COL7
3   10 hai pal    6   35   30   18
4   11     rfm    9   22   32    9
5    9     rtf    8   34   54   10
```

Comment: I find this answer useful. But a small alteration. I need the above code to work even if non-duplicate values are present in COL1 i.e. I need the above said operations done only for duplicate rows in the input df. For non-duplicate rows, i do not want any operation to happen. I have edited the question

Comment: do you want to return the rows with non-duplicate COL1 values in the output dataframe as they are or discard them?

Comment: Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names

Comment: it should work fine, can u check if your df is a data frame and if you have some extra columns in it? also check it first with the sample dataset you provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125897/discussion-between-rambo-and-sandipan).